# Tomcat Session Replication Issue on cluster nodes

Tags: java, tomcat, jmeter, tomcat7

Configuration : 
I have 2 servers on my tomcat cluster and is configured to replicate sessions. In my logs on both the instances, I see following logs somewhat frequently:

```
SEVERE: Unable to perform replication request.
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:746)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor726.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest$AttributeInfo.writeExternal(DeltaRequest.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest.writeExternal(DeltaRequest.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest.serialize(DeltaRequest.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.serializeDeltaRequest(DeltaManager.java:621)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.requestCompleted(DeltaManager.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.requestCompleted(DeltaManager.java:1018)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.send(ReplicationValve.java:537)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.sendMessage(ReplicationValve.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.sendSessionReplicationMessage(ReplicationValve.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.sendReplicationMessage(ReplicationValve.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas/information about the exceptions. Are they harmless? Can they be related to a in-use memory?

Cluster Config :

```
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" channelSendOptions="4">
      <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
               expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
               notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
      <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
           <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.StaticMembershipInterceptor">
                 <Member className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.StaticMember"
                          port="8083"
                          securePort="-1"
                          host="IP-ADDR"
                          domain="XXX.com"
                          uniqueId=""/>
          </Interceptor>
        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                  address=""
                  port="8083"
                  autoBind="100"
                  selectorTimeout="5000"
                  maxThreads="100"/>
        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
     <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
        </Sender>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
      </Channel>
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"filter=""/>
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
      <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                tempDir=""
                deployDir=""
                watchDir=""
                watchEnabled="false"/>

<ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
   <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
</Cluster>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The loadbalancer is set with stickysessions mode or not ? For me there is concurrency access eroor, so replication is in conflict with the session modification. Even if there is session replication you need to have stickysession to be sure that the user use the most current session.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Mr_Thorynque, No my Loadbalancer is not configured with sticky sessions. But this behavior of tomcat is on for some time now, earlier there was no such logs. (Tomcat version 7.0.52).

Comment: Maybe you have more activity on your server so some time there is collision between replication and session modification. Try to enable sticky session and see if this error appends.